# Electron not working out of the box on Windows bash

Tags: bash, npm, windows-10, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Electron's quick start project. I'm on Windows 10 running bash (the Ubuntu shell that comes with the OS).

Initially had some issues with npm and installed `libasound2`, `libnss3-dev`, `libgconf-2-4`, `libxss1`, and `libxtst6` to fix them.

Finally stopped getting npm errors but then got this and I'm stuck:

```
/electron-quick-start$ npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start .../electron-quick-start
> electron .

[1117:1121/213915:FATAL:render_sandbox_host_linux.cc(40)] Check failed: 0 == shutdown(renderer_socket_, SHUT_RD). shutdown: Invalid argument
#0 0x000001e5468e <unknown>
#1 0x000001e6a38b <unknown>
#2 0x000001e6a94d <unknown>
#3 0x00000292cea2 <unknown>
#4 0x0000026f5d75 <unknown>
#5 0x0000026fc0df <unknown>
#6 0x0000026f5506 <unknown>
#7 0x00000121e5b7 <unknown>
#8 0x00000121d090 <unknown>
#9 0x000003475763 main
#10 0x7f43248a1ec5 __libc_start_main
#11 0x000000575dc9 <unknown>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Given the very beta-y nature of the Windows 10 bash, I suspect this problem is not actually with Electron. Have you tried running it in cmd or another shell like environment like cmder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/758) in the Windows Insider builds, but others still remain that prevent Electron from working in WSL.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this problem (and the missing libraries you mentionned) by first installing Electron from Windows before executing it from bash.

I wrote some details on this GitHub issue : https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt/issues/260